# CSS Navigation Bar is not horizontal and has wrong colours

Tags: html, css, navigation

I made a website and was recently trying to change it completely and I am pretty much finished but my navigation bar seems to be broken as I get the wrong colours and the bar isn't horizontal.
Here is the html code:

```
<body>
<div class="content">
        <h1 class="text-center">
    <header>
        <a href="index.html">
        <img src="img/channelart.jpg" alt="Nor1Gamez"></a>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul> 
            <li><a href="index.html"> Home |</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="about/index.html"> About Me |</a></li>
                      <li><a href="razer.html"> Razer |</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/Nor1Gamez"> YouTube |</a></li>                  
                  <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Nor1Gamez"> Twitter |</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.patreon.com/Nor1Gamez"> Patreon </a></li>
        </ul> 
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

Then this is the CSS code :

```
nav ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #ffffff;
}
nav ul li {
display: inline;;
font-size: 2em;
float: left;
}

nav ul li a{
display:block;
color:#00FF00;
text-decoration:underline;
padding: 6px;
float: left;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color:#ffc0f8;
}
```

Also here is a picture of the website:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMH6u.png

Thanks !

Comment: It seems as if there's not a specific issue that can be addressed here, rather your code needs to be checked for syntax errors and unclosed tags. Check out http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the periods in your class identifiers of your CSS.

Example:

```
nav ul li a:hover{
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#ffc0f8;
}
```

Should be:

```
.nav ul li a:hover{
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#ffc0f8;
}
```

UPDATE:

Another error in your CSS appears to fix the original issue, you were missing an end bracket because you commented it out:

Should be:

```
  aside {
        width: 32%;
        height: 650px;
        display: block;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #ffffff;
  }
```

These type of mistakes can be avoided/caught more easily in the future by writing cleaner code with proper indentation. I recommend you check your code for additional errors and validate it.

Note this is in *addition* to the other suggestions made (such as removing or closing your h1 tag)

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/7e15e32t/

Is it different than how it's supposed to be displaying? If so, how specifically?

Comment: I do have to say I have tried a lot of things. I'm not sure what you changed in the fiddle but it didn't work. If you want i can upload the whole html and css file and you can look at it if that's not a problem.

Comment: The navigation bar stayed the same as in the picture.

Comment: I isolated the HTML of your navigation bar and corrected the CSS. There isn't anything wrong with that part of the code, it is elsewhere, likely in your HTML.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dxvfqzz5/ please have a look at it if you have any idea about what could be wrong.

Comment: Once the HTML suggested corrections were made and the missing period put in with "nav" in the CSS, how interesting that the problem boiled down to a commented out closing brace in the CSS code!

Answer (score 0):

`<h1 class="text-center">` Is not closed

```
<h1 class="text-center"></h1>
```

Comment: All that did is made my whole website text tiny but thanks anyway.